# Alamofire Order of parameter

Tags: swift, xcode, alamofire

I am trying to use alamofire..however the order of parameter is mixed up.. I am trying to change password from this function

```
func changePassword(uid: String, accessToken: String, currentPassword: String, newPassword: String, confirmNewPassword: String, completion: @escaping (JSON?, Error?) -> Void) {
    let parameters: [String : Any] = [
        "uid": uid,
        "current_pass" : currentPassword,
        "new_pass": newPassword,
        "confirm_new_pass": confirmNewPassword,
        "signature" : (uid + currentPassword + newPassword + confirmNewPassword)
    ]

    let URLString = MyClient.baseURL

    MyClient.request(with: URLString, method: .get, parameters: parameters) { (json, error) in
        guard error == nil, let json = json else {
            completion(nil, error)
            return
        }

        completion(json, nil)
    }
}
```

However, my parameters are not in order. Is there any ways I can go about this?

Comment: Put a clear description about what you want and what you currently getting.

Comment: I need them to be going in order of uid,current_pass,new_pass,confirm_new_pass... but in my api url, its jumbled up and not in order

Comment: are you expecting first url param to be `uid`, second url param to be `current_pass` and so on ?

Comment: yes correct, it is what i am expecting

Comment: actually you should not, thats why the key uid, cur_password etc exists.

Comment: I mean, how do i make them in order? so the url would be www.abc.php/uid=abc&curren_pass=abc and so on?

Comment: A dictionary doesn't have order, and your API shouldn't take order neither. You have a key/value system (dictionary), why use an index one (array)? If you still need that order, then construct yourself the URL in the order you want.

Comment: @Larme ok. So if there was 20 APIs used, i would need to construct 20 URLs, would that be right?

Comment: If the 20 of thems needs an order, yes. But at least, if they all have the same order, you can put the keys in an array and construct the URL according to that array where key are ordered.